# Ubuntu Multipass: permission denied

Tags: multipass

when I try to do ./ to test one of my programs it says permission denied. Is there a way to run multipass as administrator to see if that solves the problem or what could be the problem.

Comment: update. It is possible to start as admin just like any other app. however, it still says permission denied.

Comment: Any solutions on this ? Sadly to the one who closed this issue. This question is very clear about multipass on ubuntu.